# adding navigation to genesis themes

Tags: theme-development, themes, css, child-theme, genesis-theme-framework

i'm following a tutorial provided [here](http://www.studiopress.com/tips/use-navigation-bars.htm) to add navigation menu, but not able to find out set of #nav in my style.css & my theme is eleven40. What we need to replace to get navigation menu?

Answer (score 0):

`Eleven40` does not contain these styles in the style sheet. Paste all the styles listed on the tutorial page just above this line (in the child theme style.css file):

```
/* Inner
------------------------------------------------------------ */
```

Follow the other steps specified in the tutorial and you are set.

[image]